# How to set up React on IIS without rewrite rules nor Hashrouter

Tags: reactjs, iis, routes

When I deploy the React App to IIS Web Server, the pages 404. I know I can fix this issue with a rewrite rule or hash router. Is there any other way?

The set up in app.js

```
<Switch> 
  <Route exact path="/Documents/Home" component={Home} /> 
  <Route exact path="/Documents" component={Documents} /> 
  <Route component={NotFoundPage} /> 
</Switch>
```

You can set up a rewrite rule in the web.config to have IIS point to index.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
                 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                 </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
           </rule>
         </rules>
       </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Or I can wrap the routes in a HashRouter so it doesn't send the route info to the web server. though it has a /#/ in the url.

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch> 
    <Route exact path="/Documents/Home" component={Home} /> 
    <Route exact path="/Documents" component={Documents} /> 
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} /> 
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

Is there a third way of fixing this issue of routing on IIS?

Comment: URL rewrite is the only native module to process the URL on IIS. There won’t be another way. The rule of URL rewrite you set is to redirect all file request to Index.html. That’s a bit confused to me. If this rule doesn’t meet you need ,can you specify your demand? so I may help you to improve the URL rewrite rule.

Comment: I recently spent a few hours looking for an answer to this exact question. I never found one. I even looked through every option in the Azure App Service to see if there was a way to do it on the server instead of polluting my codebase with something so deployment-specific. I never found anything. Best of luck. I'm following this question in case someone has something better.